# Automatically set `TInput` equal to `TOutput` for the fluent syntax

Tags: c#, .net, fluent

I am building my personal automation framework with fluent syntax. Here is a pipeline example

```
 var pipeline = Core.Runner.CreatePipeline()
                .BeginMany(Sources.Csv(@"..."))
                .ThenTransform<dynamic,string[]>(record=> record.id.Split(":"))
                .ThenTransform<string[], (string, string)>(record => (record[0], record[1]))
                .ThenTransform<(string, string), dynamic>(new {...})
```

I wonder is there any way to improve usability and automatically set `TInput` equal to `TOutput` for the next `ThenTransform<TInput, TOutput>` in the chain and validate types on build?

Desired outcome

```
 var pipeline = Core.Runner.CreatePipeline()
                .BeginMany(Sources.Csv(@"..."))
                .ThenTransform<string[]>(record=> record.id.Split(":")) // TInput is dynamic, TOutput is string[]
                .ThenTransform<(string, string)>(record => (record[0], record[1])) // TInput is string[], TOuput is (string,string)
                .ThenTransform<dynamic>(new {...}) // etc
```

an even better outcome which might be possible because lambda knows return type

```
 var pipeline = Core.Runner.CreatePipeline()
                .BeginMany(Sources.Csv(@"..."))
                .ThenTransform(record=> record.id.Split(":")) // TInput is dynamic, TOutput is string[]
                .ThenTransform(record => (record[0], record[1])) // TInput is string[], TOuput is (string,string)
                .ThenTransform(new {...}) // etc
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to re-create LINQ. How is `ThenTransform` different from `Select`?

Comment: On that note, have you considered a `Cast<>()` method like LINQ uses? `BeginMany(...).ThenTransform(record => record.id).Cast<string>().ThenTransform(s => s.Split(":"))...`

Comment: @StriplingWarrior my pipeline works with sources rather than collections, It's a fluent wrapper around Dataflow, but similar logic, yeah. I do not need a cast right here, because I already get the needed type from lambda.

Comment: You say you already get the needed type from the lambda, but actually you don't, because anything that starts with a `dynamic` will yield another `dynamic` until you explicitly cast it to something else. In your current syntax, you're casting it by providing generic method arguments. If you want to avoid that, you could just say `.ThenTransform(record => (string)record.id)`, so you don't need a cast.

Comment: Also, I'm not convinced you're not reinventing LINQ. [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) is all about wrapping parallel pipelines in a fluent interface. [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) does the same for async stream processing. Both embrace LINQ-style syntax, which allows people to use LINQ Expression Syntax. Something to think about.

Answer (score 3):

You have not specified how you are storing state here, but for the generics you can do something like this:

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pipeline = Core.Runner.CreatePipeline<dynamic>()
                .BeginMany(Sources.Csv(@"..."))
                // Type cannot be inferred from dynamic
                .ThenTransform<string[]>(record => record.id.Split(":")) 
                .ThenTransform(record => (record[0], record[1]))
                .ThenTransform(s => s.Item1);
        }
    }

    internal class Sources
    {
        public static object Csv(string s)
        {
            return new object();
        }
    }

    internal class Core
    {
        public class Runner
        {
            public static Pipeline<TInput> CreatePipeline<TInput>()
            {
                return new Pipeline<TInput>(new PipelineState());
            }
        }
    }

    internal class PipelineState
    {
        public bool MyState { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Pipeline<TInput>
    {
        private readonly PipelineState _pipelineState;

        public Pipeline(PipelineState pipelineState)
        {
            _pipelineState = pipelineState;
        }

        public Pipeline<TInput> BeginMany(object csv)
        {
            // Update state
            return this;
        }

        public Pipeline<TOutput> ThenTransform<TOutput>(Func<TInput, TOutput> func)
        {
            // Update state
            return new Pipeline<TOutput>(_pipelineState);
        }
    }
}
```

You can probably improve upon this by having different `PipelineBuilder` classes that are returned by different methods. For instance `BeginMany` might return a class that has the `ThenTransform` method so that the order is enforced:

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pipeline = Core.Runner.CreatePipeline()
                .BeginMany(Sources.Csv(@"..."))
                // Type cannot be inferred from dynamic
                .ThenTransform<string[]>(record => record.id.Split(":"))
                .ThenTransform(record => (record[0], record[1]))
                .ThenTransform(s => s.Item1)
                .Build();
        }
    }

    internal class Sources
    {
        public static Source<dynamic> Csv(string s)
        {
            return new Source<dynamic>();
        }
    }

    internal class Source<T>
    {
    }

    internal class Core
    {
        public class Runner
        {
            public static PipelineBuilder CreatePipeline()
            {
                return new PipelineBuilder(new PipelineState());
            }
        }
    }

    internal class PipelineState
    {
        public bool MyState { get; set; }
    }

    internal class PipelineBuilder
    {
        protected readonly PipelineState State;

        public PipelineBuilder(PipelineState state)
        {
            State = state;
        }

        public PipelineBuilder<TInput> BeginMany<TInput>(Source<TInput> source)
        {
            // Update state
            return new PipelineBuilder<TInput>(State);
        }

        public Pipeline Build()
        {
            // Populate from state
            return new Pipeline();
        }
    }


    internal class PipelineBuilder<TInput> : PipelineBuilder
    {
        public PipelineBuilder(PipelineState pipelineState) : base(pipelineState)
        {
        }

        public PipelineBuilder<TOutput> ThenTransform<TOutput>(Func<TInput, TOutput> func)
        {
            // Update state
            return new PipelineBuilder<TOutput>(State);
        }
    }

    internal class Pipeline
    {
    }
}
```

It's worth looking into the builder pattern, when combined with interfaces and extension methods it can be pretty powerful. One great example is `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/tree/release/3.1/src/Configuration